# Laravel Distinct query not working in my project

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel project am trying to show google map locator, there are various kinds of services, each services may or may not be available in various clinics in various locations.Am trying to make a ajax call to my controller by passing service to fetch clinic and location details.

Problem is that if Clinic A have service X  & Service Y in location X, then it is fetching Clinc A details multiple times.I want to show the clinc details only once.

Following is my code

```
public function mapService(Request $request)
    {
        $postdata = Request::all();
        // Start XML file, create parent node
        $dom = new \DOMDocument("1.0");
        $node = $dom->createElement("markers");
        $parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);



        $services_id = isset($postdata['id'])? $postdata['id']:'';

        $apiKey = $postdata['apikey'];

        if( $services_id ) {
            $loc_services = Clinic::select('*')
                        ->join('locations', 'locations.clinicID', '=', 'clinics.clinicID')
                        ->join('location_services', 'location_services.locationID', '=', 'locations.locationID')
                        ->join('services', 'services.serviceID', '=', 'location_services.serviceID')
                        ->whereIn('services.serviceID',$services_id)
                        ->where('clinics.api_key','=',$apiKey) 
                        ->distinct()
                        ->get(); 
        }else {
            $loc_services =Clinic::select('*')
                        ->join('locations', 'locations.clinicID', '=', 'clinics.clinicID')
                        ->where('clinics.api_key','=',$apiKey) 
                        ->get();
        }


        foreach ($loc_services as $loc_service) {
            $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
            $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
            $newnode->setAttribute("id", $loc_service->locationID);
            $newnode->setAttribute("locationName", $loc_service->locationName);
            $newnode->setAttribute("locationAddress1", $loc_service->locationAddress1);
            $newnode->setAttribute("locationCity", $loc_service->locationCity);
            $newnode->setAttribute("locationState", $loc_service->locationState);
            $newnode->setAttribute("locationZip", $loc_service->locationZip);
            $newnode->setAttribute("locationLat", $loc_service->locationLat);
            $newnode->setAttribute("locationLong", $loc_service->locationLong);
            $newnode->setAttribute("serviceName", $loc_service->serviceName);
            $newnode->setAttribute("clinicName", $loc_service->clinicName);
            $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $loc_service->distance);
            $newnode->setAttribute("cname", $loc_service->clinicName);
            $newnode->setAttribute("clinicFname", $loc_service->clinicFname);
            $newnode->setAttribute("clinicLname", $loc_service->clinicLname);
            $newnode->setAttribute("clinicAddress", $loc_service->clinicAddress);
            $newnode->setAttribute("clinicCity", $loc_service->clinicCity);
            $newnode->setAttribute("clinicPhone", $loc_service->clinicPhone);
            $newnode->setAttribute("clinicstate", $loc_service->clinicState);
            $newnode->setAttribute("cliniczip", $loc_service->clinicZip);
            $newnode->setAttribute("clinicemail", $loc_service->clinicEmail);
        }

        echo $dom->saveXML();
        //$view = \View::make('api.getwazemap', ['maplocservices'=>$loc_services]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are applying 'distinct' on all your result ... this would be ineffective ..
you should apply 'distinct' only on  clinics table

try change to this:

```
$loc_services = Clinic::select('clinics.*').....
```

... it should work

Comment: It is not returning any data, sql query is error, because what data does clinincs will contain

Comment: please replace clinics  by the table name of the model Clinic